# How to escape rethinkdb regex pattern for r.match

Tags: python, regex, rethinkdb

I want to search with r.match in rethinkdb using user input - whole user input should be treated as search pattern. I'm creating regex based on user input like this:

```
pattern = u'.*(?i){0}.*'.format(user_input)
```

But if user inputs '[' or ']' or any other special character I got errors from rethink like this:

> Error in regexp `.*(?i)\u0141[.*` (portion `[.*`): missing ]: [.* in:

Is there any way to escape regex for rethinkdb? I have tried to use python re.escape but this fail when combining unicode with errors like this one:

> Error in regexp `.*(?i)\\u0141.*` (portion `\\u0141`): invalid escape sequence: \u0141

Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't know if this is still relevant for you since the question was asked 4 years ago but in case someone else stumbles across it I had the same issue and found a workaround for it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55435019/8952681 Hope it answers your question and solves this mystery.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `re.escape()` function for this:

[`re` escape](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.escape)

> **escape(string)**
>
> Return string with all non-alphanumerics backslashed; this is useful if you want to match an arbitrary literal string that may have regular expression metacharacters in it.

Comment: I was trying to do so, but when using unicode I got errors like this one: Error in regexp .*(?i)\\u0141.* (portion \\u0141): invalid escape sequence: \u0141